# Working with Azure DocumentDB and adding object to Document

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am working on a Library application or so to say that has to connect to Azure DocumentDB. In my DocumentDB I have a DocumentCollection that is BookCollection and a Document - BookDocument. Everytime a new Book is added into the system, this Document has to be updated with the new Book object and my question is: How do I do that? So far I have this:

```
public static async Task AddBook(Book newBook)
{
using (_client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(_endPointURL),_authKey))            
{

            Database database = (from db in _client.CreateDatabaseQuery()
                where db.Id == "BookAssignment"
                select db).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Database: " + database.Id);
            //Create collection
            string dbCollectionBooks = "Books";
            DocumentCollection dbCollection =
                (from collections in _client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(database.SelfLink)
                    where collections.Id == dbCollectionBooks
                    select collections).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

            if (dbCollection == null)
            {
                dbCollection =
                    await
                        _client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink,
                            new DocumentCollection() {Id = dbCollectionBooks});
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to DocumentCollection" + dbCollection.Id);
            //Document
            string doucmentID = "BookDocument";
            Document document = (from documents in _client.CreateDocumentQuery(database.SelfLink)
                where documents.Id == doucmentID
                select documents).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
            if (document == null)
            {
                var _newBook = new Book();
                _newBook.Bookcase.Category = newBook.Bookcase.Category;
                _newBook.ISBN = newBook.ISBN;
                _newBook.Title = newBook.Title;
                _newBook.Author = newBook.Author;
                _newBook.RealeaseDate = newBook.RealeaseDate;
                _newBook.Colour = newBook.Colour;
                _newBook.Genre = newBook.Genre;
                document = await _client.CreateDocumentAsync(dbCollection.SelfLink, _newBook);
                BookContainer.Add(_newBook);
            }               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for the ReplaceDocumentAsync method.

Your call will look something like 
await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(document.SelfLink, _newBook);

Keep in mind that you can also create document queries with a specific type (e.g. Book) if you need to check some properties of the existing document before updating it.